# Is the sentence "What social problems exist in big cities" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

An English class use this as the topic for students.

> What social problems exist in big cities

[image]

Typically, to construct a [wh-question](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/questions-wh-questions), one needs to use an auxiliary verb, such as "do/does", which the quoted sentence doesn't have one. So, is the sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: *Typically, to construct a question, one needs to use an auxiliary verb, such as "do/does."* ***Really? Are you sure?*** First, *typically* doesn't mean *always*. But, that aside, where have you learned this as a rule?

Comment: @JasonBassford https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/questions-wh-questions

Comment: Ah! It makes more sense with that edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule "to construct a question, one needs to use an auxiliary verb, such as 'do/does'" does not apply when what is being asked is the subject, because, if what is asked is the subject, it is obviously not possible to have subject-auxiliary inversion (where would we place the auxiliary if the subject is in front position?).

Therefore, questions asking for the subject and introduced by *who, what, which, whose, how much/many* are followed by the verb as it will appear in the answer:

- What social problems **exist** in big cities?
- Problems such as pollution, crime and unemployment **exist** in big cities.
- Which **represents** the worst problem?
- Pollution **represents** the worst problem.
- How many poeople **live** in big cities?
- Millions of people people **live** in big cities.
- Who **lives** in a big city?
- I **live** in a big city.

By the way, in the source you just quoted you can read:

**Warning:**

When *what, who, which* or *whose* is the subject or part of the subject, we do not use the auxiliary. We use the word order subject + verb:

*What fell off the wall? Which horse won? Who bought this? Whose phone rang?*

Answer (score 0):

(1) When wh-word is the subject or part of the subject of the question,

> Wh-word [subject] + verb

e.g., *[**Who**] wrote 'The Merchant of Venice'?*

*[**What** social problems] exist in big cities?*

The bracketed part is the subject.

(2) When wh-word is not the subject,

> Wh-word + Auxiliary verb + Subject + Main Verb ...

e.g., *What do you want?*

(Subject = You, Verb = want, Object = what)

*Where will you go?*

(Subject = you, Verb = will go, Adverbial = Where).